# Ubuntu 18.04 Software Center opens then closes

Tags: software-installation, software-center

When I try to open the software center, it loads, then almost immediately closes itself. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall it using the following

```
sudo apt-get remove software-center
sudo apt-get autoremove software-center
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software center
```

When I tried to remove and autoremove the software center, I received the following prompt... ...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'software-center' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

And after attempting to install the software center I received the following prompt... ...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Somebody Please Help!
Thanks in Advance!

Yossef

Comment: What happens if you type gnome-software into terminal? Are there any messages shown after you hit enter?

Comment: When I type in gnome-software into the terminal, the software center opens and closes (like it usually does) and in the terminal I get a segmentation fault. @hiigaran

Comment: It also says "internal error: failed, but no error code: cancelled-priority" and "Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding", then it seg faults. @hiigaran

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your post when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.